# Como faço para colocar um botão de fechar no meu arquivo python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if, for, while

Estou começando em python e estou escrevendo um código, mas quando todas as ações acabam o programa fecha, como faço para colocar um comando onde clique por exemplo em ESC e ele feche? Quero que quando a pessoa não digite Youtube, ela possa escrever novamente, ao envés de fechar.

```
ver = input()
if ver == 'Youtube' :
        print('Abrindo youtube...')

        import webbrowser

        webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com/', new=2)

else:

        print('Desculpe, não entendi')
```

Comment: Use um [while](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#while)

Answer (score 0):

Neste caso em específico, a maneira de tratar o problema de uma forma simples e objetiva, na minha visão, seria determinando uma função para receber o input em questão.

**Ficaria mais ou menos assim:** A função exibe a mensagem de input para o usuário e recebe o dado. Após passar pela condicional e cair no else, você poderia simplesmente exibir um print informando que a digitação foi inválida e chamar a função novamente.

---

**Em código, ficaria parecido com isso:**

```
    import webbrowser
    
    def insere_URL():
        ver = input("Digite o aplicativo desejado: ")
    
        if ver == 'Youtube' :
                print('Abrindo youtube...')
                webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com/', new=2)
        else:
                print('Desculpe, não entendi. Tente novamente...')
                insere_URL()
    
    insere_URL()
```

**Dicas e observações:** Sempre faça seus imports logo no início do programa e atente-se um pouco mais para a indentação do seu código. Tente pular linha apenas quando a próxima instrução não for relacionada à de cima, como por exemplo, não é necessário pular linha após um if ou else já que o que está logo abaixo faz parte daquele bloco. Porém, se dentro do bloco tiverem códigos que façam atividades diferentes, vale uma pulação de linha ^^

Também é interessante exibir um texto dentro do input() para o usuário saber o que deve digitar.

!! IMPORTANTE !!! Nunca se esqueça de chamar a função, pois caso o contrário ela não será executada!

---

Estou iniciando em Python igualmente a você e pontuo que esta é uma maneira bastante simples e talvez até pouco recomendada de resolver isto, mas sem dúvidas é uma boa forma de iniciar as tratativas de entrada de dados do usuário em seu sistema.

**EDIT 1** A função que permite interromper a execução do seu código é:  exit()